# Add additional data to getScript jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, getscript

I want to inject script like this using jQuery `getScript` function

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://app.test.com/test.js"
        data-client-key="321jj33-dasd333"
></script>
```

I want to add that extra variable with its `value` which is `data-client-key`.

What I've done so far is like this:

```
var test = "https://app.test.com/test.js";

$.getScript(test, function(){
  $.ajax({    
    //post data using ajax
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a script tag with jQuery like this

```
var script = $("<script>");
script.attr("src", "YOUR_URL");
script.attr("data-client-key", "CLIENT-KEY");
$("head").append(script);
```

Hope it help you